# button won't stay in UIControlStateHighlighted

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to get a UIButton to change it's background image when the user clicks it.  I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)indicatedButton:(id)sender
{
[sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blankTickBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"completeTickBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

When I run the app on simulator, the image @"completeTickBox.png" flashes up for the second or so I have the mouse clicked on the button and then reverts to the original image.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing the expected behaviour of what `UIControlStateHighlighted` is designed for, I think you need `UIControlStateSelected` instead of `UIControlStateHighlighted`. Using this way it will take the selected image until its state is selected.